# jQuery Appending Attribute to Elements That Contain The Specified Text Node

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

For example, I would like to append `selected="selected"` to the option that contains **This one**, which jQuery selector should be used to append attributes into that element?

```
<select>
    <option>Not this</option>
    <option>This one</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no `value` attributes, then the text becomes the value, so you can just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("select").val("This one");
```

Or, if it has a `value="something"` attribute, use that instead:

```
$("select").val("something");
```

Comment: So I should use $("select").val("This one").attr('selected', 'selected'); to append it?

Comment: @user435216 - nope just `.val("value")`, this sets which one is selected (setting the attribute behind the scenes) :)